# ADB file transfer works on internal storage but not SD card

Tags: adb, external-sd, file-transfer

I am trying to transfer a large amount of files (>40k images and videos). I've had trouble transferring it by dragging and dropping in Windows File Explorer so I used the `adb push` command. It works on the internal storage of my phone just fine. However, when I try to do it on my SD card, it just refuses to start. It would be stuck at "daemon started successfully". I've tried restarting my computer, my phone and the adb connection, still same thing.

This is the command I tried:

```
adb push "D:\Pictures and Videos" "storage/A01D-69AC"
```

Phone Model: Xperia 1 III
SD Card: Toshiba Exceria 256 GB

Comment: expected behaviour, no permissions

Comment: @alecxs thank you, do you happen to know what i need to do to fix that?

Comment: @alecxs does not seem to be a permission problem, i manage to move single files using the same command, might just be a size issue

Comment: How old is the SD-card? What file-system  is the SD-card formatted with? As it is larger as 64Gb it should be formatted as FATex by default.

Comment: @Robert i am using toshiba exceria 256 gb exFAT formatted, the sd card is about half a year old.

Comment: @alecxs i've tried using usb 2.0, same issue. For now, i am just using an sd card reader to transfer the files.

Comment: The adb command in your question uses the path `storage/A01D-69AC`. I think this path missed the leading slash to be correct (to become an absolute path).

Comment: try adb over tcpip (wifi)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in the folder in your computer.

then do this:

> `adb push D:\PicturesandVideos /storage/A01D-69AC/`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).